# Jenikns java errors

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, utf-8

I installed Jenkins on AWS EC2 Linux server. When I want to do anything in Jenkins, (edit configuration, create a project, etc.) I get errors such as:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not valid encoding '%'
```

From what I found, it might be the problem with UTF 8 encoding. I was trying to solve it by adding `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack` and `LANG=Dfile.encoding=UTF8` to `bash_profile` and `bashrc` files but it seems that it didn't help. Any ideas how I can solve it?

My `bash_profile` scirpt:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.201.b09-0.43.amzn1.x86_64
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:$LANG:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

And `bashrc`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US:en
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Neither of them had any effect.

Edit: This is full error example:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not valid encoding '%'
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeHexByte(UrlEncoded.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeUtf8To(UrlEncoded.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.UrlEncoded.decodeTo(UrlEncoded.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:387)
Caused: org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 400: Unable to parse form content
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameters(Request.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1056)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.extractCrumbFromRequest(CrumbFilter.java:112)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try restarting the Jenkins service
2. Hope you don't have a password with % / ) - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54409

Comment: Restarting Jenkins didn't help and I do not have password with %.

Comment: Can you please post the full error exception message?